# spying on/mocking super class methods in es6

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, ecmascript-6

The below are examples but get at the gist of my problem ...

super class:

```
class Parent {
  constructor(a) {
    this._a = a;
  }

  doSomething() { ... implementation... }
}
```

child-class:

```
class Child extends Parent {
  constructor() {
    super('a');
  }

  doSomethingElse() { return super.doSomething(); }
}
```

I am using these classes in Angular, so the Parent class is DI'ed into the factory which provides the Child class, something like this:

```
 function ChildDeps(Parent) {
     return class Child extends Parent {
          ... Child class implementation here ...
     };
 }

 ChildDeps.$inject = ['Parent']
```

Naively, I first tried something like this inside a provide before each clause:

```
beforeEach(module($provide => {
  parent = {
    doSomething: jasmine.createSpy('parent.doSomething')
  };
  Parent = jasmine.createSpy('Parent').and.returnValue(parent);
  $provide.value('Parent', Parent);
}));
```

But this did not work ... saying that spy 'Parent' was never called.

Currently using jasmine/karma for testing. How can mock/spy the super class so I can make expectations about what the Parent class' constructor is called with and that the `super.doSomething` function is called?

Thanks!

Comment: You'd need to overwrite `Parent` before evaluating `child-class.js`. Reassigning the global variable later won't change the inheritance chain of `Child`.

Comment: Try `Object.setPrototypeOf(Child, jasmine.createSpy('Parent'))`  and `Object.setPrototypeOf(Child.prototype, parent)`. That should lead the `super`  calls to their spied-on targets.

Comment: How do you wrap your `Child` class into angular module? It is important to answer to your question

Comment: @just-boris -- i edited the question to include that, thanks!

Comment: You have a typo. There should be `ChildDeps.$inject = ['Parent']`

Comment: Don't know about angular, but this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58410532/how-to-replace-javascript-method-of-super-class-for-testing/58410929#58410929