# How to replace javascript method of super class for testing?

Tags: javascript, testing, super

I want to test a method 'foo' that calls its super method 'foo':

```
foo(){
     super.foo();
     //do some extra stuff
}
```

If it would reference another method from the same class, e.g.

```
foo(){
     this.baa();
     //do some extra stuff
}
```

... i could simply replace the baa method for testing, e.g

```
element.baa = () => { console.log('This is a mock of baa')};
element.foo();

expect(effectsOfFoo).toBe(Ok).
```

However, how to replace the super method 'foo'?

Maybe something like

```
element.constructor.getSuperClass().foo = () => { console.log('This is a mock of super foo')};
```

However, I did not manage to get the super class, yet.

Related questions:

[spying on/mocking super class methods in es6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35304250/spying-on-mocking-super-class-methods-in-es6)

Answer (score 0):

```
element.constructor.__proto__.prototype.foo = () => {
                        console.log('This is a mock of super foo');
                    };
```